# How to generate all possible nxm arrays, if each element is binary (can only take on 0 or 1). Preferably in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations, permutation

I am essentially trying to generate all possible nxm matrices. I have seen some codes in R and Python that kind of does this with a single function, but I cant find anything similar for matlab :(

Comment: Editing my previous comment, just saw that you're suggesting the entries are binary. So N and M are integers that you set? You should provide more information about your problem, or consider generating a minimum reproducible example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Lets assume your rows are binary numbers of length `m`, it means that there exist `2^m -1` possible numbers. Now when saying that you want to create "ALL possible" matrices you mean you are looking for all permutations with a fixed length of n?

Comment: How large are your `n` and `m` likely to be? You'll run out of space in a `double` by the time you get to a 7x8 array if you use the `dec2bin` approach. Do you need to generate all of the arrays at once, or just one at a time? Why do you need to generate all of the possible arrays at all?

Answer (score 0):

here's a way to do that in matlab:

```
n=4;
m=3;

for c=0:2^(n*m)-1
    A(:,c+1)=str2double(split(dec2bin(c,n*m),'',1));
end 

A(1,:)=[]; A(end,:)=[];
A=reshape(A,n,m,[]);
```

the logic, it doesnt matter if it is an nxm array or a 1D vector of length nxm, we can later reshape the vector to an nxm array (last line). Then, the # of possible permutation for a binary string of Length L is just all the decimal # from 0 to  2^L-1 transformed to binary string of length nxm. This is what the `dec2bin(...)` function does. Then we get a long string (for example '010001010111') that needs to be `split` to individual elements('0','1',...) , so we can later convert this strings to numbers using `str2double`.  The `split(...)` function does that but generates `NaN` at the edges, so we get rid of them in the row before the last one...

so for this example I chose n=4, m=3, which generates just 2^(nxm)=4096 possible array... 
you can see them if if you try `A(:,:,j)` with `j` being a # from 1 to 4096

Comment: you should be able to generate the matrix `A` in the following way `dec2bin(2^(n*m)-1:-1:0)-'0' `, this will save you few lines and the treatment of special cases of `NaN`.